# MVC2 FormCollection options

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, formcollection

I'm just getting started with MVC2 and going through the NerdDinner examples.  I noticed that there seems to be multiple ways to pass in the form values for example:

```
FormColelction formvalues
FormCollection collection
FormCollection form
```

Why would you use one over the other and why?
Does it also relate to whether you are using Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1):

Each of the above examples is passing in the same type (FormCollection) but with just a different variable name.

It would have been nice to see some consistency in NerdDinner.

You can also have MVC automagically populate a custom object from your form instead of using the generic FormCollection.

EG If your form being posted has fields for FirstName, LastName and Age (representing a person) you could have a method like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Person person)
{
    //person is already populated    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "id")]Person post_person)
{
      // post_person => auto populate formpost values 
      // [Bind(Exclude = "id")] => excluding auto populate identity field 
}
```